# Can not access to Internet on virtual XP

Tags: 12.04, networking, virtualbox, windows-xp

I' m using VirtualBox on Ubuntu 12.04 to run virtual XP. I cannot access to Internet. I have read the  [How to let a VirtualBox guest (running Windows) access the Internet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/232876/how-to-let-a-virtualbox-guest-running-windows-access-the-internet), but it seems does not work. I really appreciate your help! : ) Thanks !

Here is my settings.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

From Ubuntu 12.04 dns name resolve changed so that you should add "dns-nameservers" parameter to your /etc/network/interfaces file, like :

```
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```